# C# Microsoft.Extensions.Logging how to redirect output to a specific file?

Tags: c#, .net, logging

I am using `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` to output some data and wondering if I could redirect output to a specific file rather than the console. Here is my code:

```cs
  var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(loggingBuilder => loggingBuilder
                        .SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace).AddConsole());

  ILogger logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<DataLogger>();
  string path = GenerateFilePath();
  logger.LogInformation("DataLogger is initialized.");
  // todo: redirect output to path.
```

Is there a way I can redirect my output to the file `path`?

Comment: use library like serilog to write to file

Comment: Microsoft does not provide out of the box File logging. It only provides 4, which Console, DebugLogger, EventSource, and EventViewer. If you would want to write to a file, use Serilog like @CodingMytra suggested which supports a file sink (and even better, a seq sink)

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, your best bet is [serilog](https://serilog.net/)

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File" Version="3.0.0" />
```

Add the service...

```cs
WebApplicationBuilder builder;
// create configure etc etc

builder.Services.AddLogging(logbuilder =>
    logbuilder.AddFile(builder.Configuration.GetSection("FileLogging"))
);
```

... and this section to yout appsettings.json

```json
    "FileLogging": {
        "PathFormat": "logs/myapp.{Date}.log",
        "RetainedFileCountLimit": 69,
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Warning",
            "MyNamespace": "Trace",
            "Microsoft": "Error"
        }
    },
```

you could configure everything as a delegate in AddLogging but i strongly suggest to add it to your configuration file.

for more info, it has it's own tag on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serilog